# Web Hosting: Any web host that supports files more than 50,000 in number?

Tags: mysql, php, web-hosting

For my **PHP & mySQL** based application, I am trying to buy website hosting from a host who does not have a limit on the number of files I carry in my hosting account. Almost all the websites have a common limit of 50,000 files (some websites call it 50,000 nodes). The rest(to the extent of my search) are not even close. I have gone through the various websites, Googled lot of information, have spoken with the customer service of the hosting companies and they said that they have a limit of 50,000 files and that's why they call it the LIMIT.

Now I have my application, which is a kind of social networking website, where people can upload various files of varying file size. So say if 50,000 users were to join the website and upload 1 file each, the limit of 50,000 will be reached very easily and my 50,001 customer will start facing file upload problems (& so will my account). So I would like to know if there's any website hosting services that do **NOT** levy such restrictions. In summary, I need the following options:

1. No maximum file limit (more than 50,000 files in account).
2. No maximum file upload limit in server setting (10MB, 12MB, 15MB, 20MB, etc.).
3. Ability to upload files of various types (zip, flv, jg, png, etc.).
4. Ability to stream Audio and Video (live audio & video not necessary).
5. Access to .htaccess
6. Access to php.ini, my.cnf or my.ini (this would be a plus)
7. Supports SSL.
8. Provides dedicated hosting(& IP) as well.
9. Monthly payments without contracts are a plus.

If you know of any such website hosting services, please post a reply ( a link to the same will be appreciated ).

Thank you.

Comment: Buy/rent a dedicated server or virtual machine, and you will have very few restrictions. You'll just need to know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to go with a VPS service where you own the whole (virtual) machine. Many web hosts have both a shared option *and* a VPS option, so you can go with the shared service (and live with the limits) until your site gets popular. By the time your site is popular enough to *need* 50,000 files you will hopefully have a revenue stream in place that'll cover the cost of a VPS service (at least!)

Comment: @codeka You are very right about the cost of a VPS service and about the methodology of going with the shared server and then going VPS once the site becomes popular. In fact, that's what I had in mind. So do you know of any good web hosts that offer VPS hosting (& shared) at a good price? Thanks.

Comment: I do most of my hosting in Australia, so that's where most of my experience is. I've heard good things about http://www.dreamhost.com/ in the U.S. though.

Comment: I will go through dreamhost.com. You mentioned that you do your hosting in Australia. So which company do you prefer? How is their customer service in case of any problems? Any other references are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use http://www.slicehost.com/
You have to set up all you own stuff but it is fun and you can use your resources as you deem fit.

Comment: Slicehost are owned by Rackspace and their Rackspace Cloud service is much better value for money IMO, and they've given me 5 minutes of downtime in the past 4 months.

Comment: @Randy That's a good link. Thanks for the same. Their basic plan starts with $20, so I was wondering if there's a way to get started with a less expensive plan until the website catches up and more visitors start signing up. Once a significant amount of users sign up, I can then switch to the expensive plans. Hopefully you know of such plans that they have to offer.

Comment: @Matt, any specific link for the Rackserver service, where I can read more info in detail? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Randy. Slicehost is confusing for me. But still a worthy bookmark. +1 for you.